# Determining if TCP connection can stay up for 30 minutes without anything being received from its peer

Tags: networking, tcp, server, connection

The description of the questions goes like this:

Someone recorded all the IP packets of a TCP connection between a client and a server for 30 minutes. In the record, he didn't find any packet that was ACK-only. How is this possible?

What is claimed to be  a possible solution: For all the record time, the server sent data to the client, which the client processed, but he didn't send any data back to the server.

I am having trouble understanding how can it be possible.

From what I see, since the client didn't send any data to the server, and there weren't any ACK-only packets in the record, then the server didn't get any ACK from the client. Logically, I would think that since no ACK is received by the server, it will always do re-transmit. But also, since the server doesn't get anything from the client for 30 minutes, which seems like a long time for me, it will conclude that the connection is broken and stop it. (maybe even send an ACK only, but I am not sure about it).

Moreover, from what I know, when using keepalive, the sender gets and ACK-only packet from his peer.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: This kind of question would be more on-topic on [networkengineering.se].

Comment: Thanks, I'll post it there

Comment: What exactly is strange about this? I've had. TCP connections up for weeks in a LAN without traffic. Thiis was a nkey design feature of TCP: 'there is no dial tone'; and that is why the TCP keepalive feature is described in the RFCs as controversial.

Comment: So, your connection held up even without the keepalive feature? And there was nothing at all passed from source 1 to source 2?

Comment: Without traffic. I already said that. This is normal. There is no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more details would be helpful here. What kind of server/client? What protocol is being used and for what purpose? 
Is the connection running as expected and this is just viewed as strange traffic you are trying to understand or is the connection timing out?
Some devices or softwares can be set to a "No ACK" state which means that no ACKs are sent nor are they expected.
One reason for this is usually bandwidth. ACKs do consume bandwidth and there are cases where bandwidth is such a great premium that packets being lost is preferable to bandwidth being consumed by ACKs. That type of traffic would probably do better with a UDP protocol but that is a completely different topic.
Another reason is that you don't care if packets are lost. Again, this would be better off as UDP instead of TCP, but someone may be trying to work within strange parameters is bending the rules about what type of traffic to advertise as in order to get around some issue. 
Hopefully this is helpful, but if it does not apply, then please put in more details about the connection so that we can better understand what may be happening.

Comment: There aren't actually a lot of details given in the question. The connection is TCP as I written. The question is more in general. I you still need more details, let's say the it is an ordinary connection in linux that uses sockets. Hope it gives a little more to work with.

Comment: This is an exam question to which the OP wants the answer, as explained in the comments [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/60632/8499). It is a purely hypothetical question, not a question about something that really happened.

Comment: How would such a device ever manage to tay connected? Everything sent would be retransmitted until the sender timed out its ACK timers and reset the connection.